# What is a basis for $L^2(\Bbb R)$ ? ($\Bbb R$ is the real field)

Tags: real-analysis

I know the basis of $L^2(D)$ if $D$ is connected closed interval. But i do not know this.

Comment: What do you mean by *the* basis? There are many many bases for every vector space.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about the Hamel Basis then I don't think there's an explicit construction of it. However, if you're talking about Schauder Basis then an example would be the **Hermite function**:
$$
\phi_n(x)=e^{-\frac{x^2}2}H_n(x)
$$
where $H_n$'s are the [Hermite Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials).

Answer (score 3):

I think one example would be

$$ \left\{ x \mapsto \chi_{[-n, 1-n]}\psi(x+n) : n \in \mathbb{Z}, \psi \in B \right\} $$

where $\chi$ is the characteristic function and $B$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2([0,1])$.